# MySQL/phpMyAdmin: remove all the rows less 3 concrete

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to remove all the rows of my table less 3 concrete rows.

What was the best way to do it?

Regards

Javi

Comment: whats the problem using `DELETE` ? use it with `where` clause to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to delete everything except the IDs 56, 57, and 58:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (56, 57, 58);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the size of the table, but the easy way would be to just delete all the rows except the ones you want to keep, like so:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

If the table is large, that might take a while, so a better option might be to create a temp table, insert the three rows you want to keep into it, truncate the original table, then re-insert the 3 rows.